# Private Testnet 404 issue

Tags: transactions, stellar-core, horizon, payments, ledger

I am working on stellar private testnet setup, i have setup 3 stellar-core nodes and horizon, Account creation is working fine but data not showing for ledger, payment, transactions etc.

All 3 nodes started with `--forcescp` to sync SCP.

> Account details :

`http://xxx.xx.xxx.xx:8000/accounts/GBSLXG57SGOCTM6VWR75H5H6XTM6XNGNUYP2VTPV77Z6JA5SZVU2OBDU`

> but for same account transaction is 404 :

`http://xxx.xx.xxx.xx:8000/accounts/GBSLXG57SGOCTM6VWR75H5H6XTM6XNGNUYP2VTPV77Z6JA5SZVU2OBDU/transactions`

> Ledger with sequence 1 also having no records :

```
http://xxx.xx.xxx.xx:8000/ledgers/1
```

> 2 Nodes are basic validator and 1 is full validator, history files are maintained properly.

Not getting why data is not available ? any suggestion/solution ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> I managed to fix the issue. steps fixed for me.

```
1. Use stable version for horizon and stellar-core.
2. Use --ingest flag with horizon start.
```

Answer (score 1):

You will need to start Horizon with the ingest flag enabled in order for Horizon to ingest data from stellar core. Quoting from the [admin guide in the documentation](https://github.com/stellar/go/blob/master/services/horizon/internal/docs/reference/admin.md#ingesting-stellar-core-data):

> To enable ingestion, you must either pass --ingest=true on the command
>   line or set the INGEST environment variable to "true".